# What font does Wolfram Alpha use for its results?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

What font does Wolfram Alpha use for its results?
During my research on the internet I came across the following URL:
[Styles and Fonts in Output—Wolfram Language Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StylesAndFontsInOutput.html)

Three fonts are named within the linked web page: Courier, Times and Helvetica
Does Wolfram Alpha use any of these for its results? If one of these fonts is used, specify what!

Comment: @Glorfindel on this site [tag:font] is a meta-tag so it should not be used.

Comment: @Rubén sure, could you add that to the excerpt so that that's more obvious? :)

Comment: [tag:font] just was cleaned-up :) Related [Let's clean up some meta tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696/88163)